# sulu 2.2: Ist there a way that categories in the category_selection content type are sorted automatically by name?

Tags: sulu

Is there a way that the displayed categories of the `category_selection` content type are sorted by name rather then id? They are loaded via ajax from the api like `http://localhost:8000/admin/api/categories?locale=de&selectedIds=7&fields=name,id&flat=true`

If there is a stable way to add a sort like in the category overview, it would be a great addition.

Comment: Please see the thread in the asnwer below: this is now the default behaviour of sulu 2.2.x-dev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to sort them out of the box alphabetically.

But you can override the `CategoryController` and add `$listBuilder->sort($fieldDescriptors['name']);` after the `initializeListBuilder` call in the `getListRepresentation` method.

Edit:
I just found out, that we need a default sort order anyway, otherwise the result order can differ between two identical request. I created a pull request with the changes
https://github.com/sulu/sulu/pull/6136

Until this fix is released, you can just override your `CategoryController` and add the sorting manually.

Edit2: How to override the Controller:

First you have to create your own Controller and extend from the `CategoryController` and override the specific method e.g.:

```
class CustomCategoryController extends SuluCategoryController
{
protected function getListRepresentation(
    Request $request,
    $locale,
    $parentId = null,
    $expandedIds = [],
    $expandSelf = false,
    $includeRoot = false
) {
    $listBuilder = $this->initializeListBuilder($locale);
     <add default sort here>
     <copy the rest of the original function here>
    }
}
```

The second step is to add this service to the `services.yaml` file and add an alias to override the original CategoryController:

```
App\Controller\Admin\CustomCategoryController:
    alias: sulu_category.category_controller
```

Comment: Wow, thank you! If your time allows, do you have maybe a short hint on how to override a controller? I guess it is defined and used as a service and can be done via the services.yml as [outlined in the docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/service_decoration.html)?

Comment: @Andreas I've edited my post and added the instructions to override the controller.

Comment: Thx mate, this saved me quite some time of trial and error!

Comment: Alright, the current combination of this method beeing private and it also accessing private properties prevents an override pretty much. I opened this PR to make it protected: https://github.com/sulu/sulu/pull/6143

Comment: alright, I checked you default sort PR again, and it does do already everything needed from us, so I closed mine (overriding the controller in reality turned out more complicated then anticipated anyway). Fngers crossed, that it get's merged fast.

Comment: @Andreas aw snap, I wasn't aware of all the private stuff... you would have override and copy the original `getListRepresntation` method into your customController and add the sorting after the `initializeListBuilder`, but this is also somewhat cumbersome (edited my answer to override the `getListRepresentation`)

I will try to get my pr merged as fast as possible :)